# Java - find duplicated elements in array and display them as subarray

Tags: java, arrays

I need to find all duplicated array elements and display them as separate subarrays. Something like this:

Array = {1,7,4,3,5,5,2,1,1,8,9,8,0,1,1,2}

1. Array0 = {0}
2. Array1 = {1,1,1,1,1}
3. Array2 = {2,2}
4. Array3 = {3}
5. Array4 = {4}

...etc...

What I've done:

- generate array
- sort it ascending

I'm trying to figure out, how to approach to loop through sorted array and split it into separate subarrays containing duplicated elements.

Comment: You don't need to sort the array. You can simply use a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` that holds the value in your array as the key, and how many times that value occurs as the value. Afterwards, you can iterate through your original array once and count each integer's occurrences.

Comment: can you use collections??

Answer (score 0):

You could create another array and add the values to the corresponding number if you know the range of values. However as was mentioned using a HashMap would be a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I know the range of values. It's from 1 to 10 :) I was considering creating another array(s) and put there my numbers, but I don't know if it will be a good solution. I need to create 10 arrays in my case, right?

Comment: You would only need 1 array and just use 'position-1' for which number you're at within the array(since it starts at 0) or you could leave 0 blank and do 1-10 if you don't really care and don't want to mess up the logic.

ie. if a 5 appears you increase Array[4] by 1. It's a dirty method though and I would suggest looking up hashmaps and learning them unless you're in a rush.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic method below for separating duplicated items:

```
public static <T> HashMap<T, List<T>> getDuplicates(T[] array){
    HashMap<T, List<T>> result = new HashMap<T, List<T>>();
    for(T item : array){
        List<T> duplicates = result.get(item);
        if(duplicates == null)
            result.put(item, duplicates = new ArrayList<T>());
        duplicates.add(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Next, you can sort result collections by method:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<List<T>> getSorted(HashMap<T, List<T>> groups){
    List<List<T>> sortedGroups = new ArrayList<>(groups.values());
    Collections.sort(sortedGroups, new Comparator<List<T>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(List<T> g1, List<T> g2) {
            if(g1.isEmpty())
                return -1;
            else if(g2.isEmpty())
                return 1;
            else 
                return g1.get(0).compareTo(g2.get(0)); 
        }
    });
    return sortedGroups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using arrays and Arraylists.

I created another array arr2[] as a copy of this array and started comparing all values.
The results would be added to a temporary Arraylist which will be added to the main output collection `Arraylist<ArrayList<Integer>`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class temp
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int arr[]=  {1,7,4,3,5,5,2,1,1,8,9,8,0,1,1,2};
        int arr2[]= Arrays.copyOf(arr,arr.length);


        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrList= new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();  

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> tempArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int count=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {

            if(arr[i]==arr2[j] &&arr2[j]!=-1)
            {   tempArr.add(arr[i]);
                arr2[j]=-1;
            }
        }
        if(tempArr.size()>1) arrList.add(tempArr);
    }

    for(ArrayList c: arrList)
    {           
        System.out.println(c);
    }

}




}
```

Output:

```
[1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 8, 9, 8, 0, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[5, 5]
[2, 2]
[8, 8]
```